# Limit of a cotangent function.

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, limits

$$\lim_{z \to 0} -\pi^2\csc^2(\pi z) = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{-\pi^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)} $$

How to go about this?

Comment: As written, it's just the definition of $\csc$ that's used, $\csc w = \frac{1}{\sin w}$.

Comment: Your title does not match the question.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $\lim_{z \to 0} \sin(z)/z = 1$, this can be verified with the Taylor series of $\sin$, or by using the definition of the derivative. If we multiply and divide by $z^2$ we find:

$$\lim_{z\to 0} -\frac1{z^2} \cdot \left(\frac{-\pi z}{\sin(\pi z)}\right)^2.$$

Now the term in the parenthesis approaches $1$ as $z\to 0$. If $z$ were real, we would conclude that the limit is $-\infty$, since the magnitude of $1/z^2$ blows up as $z \to 0$, and the quantity is negative. However, if you are wanting an answer in terms of complex analysis, we would declare that the limit is $\infty$, since we don't distinguish between $\pm \infty$ in the complex numbers. (Infinity corresponds to the north pole of the Riemann sphere).